# Regular expression all parts a word

Tags: .net, regex, cpu-word, onkeypress

I need a regular expression that matches a word. However the expression must be valid until the word is completed.

Example: Using the word "stackoverflow"

all parts of words must be valid
"s"
"st"
"sta"
"stac"
"stack"
"stacko" .... so on until the complete word.

if there is "stt" is invalid.

Also have to consider that the words "stackoverflowx" or "xstackoverflow" are invalid

Thank you all.

Comment: A regex matching a word could be something like \b\w+\b. However "matching parts" contradicts "matching a word". Please be more exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that sounds it would be much better solved with

```
var input = "st"; // or "sta", or ...
bool isValid = "stackoverflow".StartsWith(input);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/yMqM1)**.

Is there some reason you have to use a regular expression?

Comment: If you dont want static strings, I suggest you look up on tries and and use one.

Comment: @leppie: Is that addressed to me or to the OP?

Comment: You're right. "StartWith" solves the problem.
I was only thinking about using regex.

But I was curious. It is possible to use regex for this?

Comment: @Jon: Sorry that was meant as additional info for the OP.

Comment: @Jonathan: It is, but it would be a *really* bad idea to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Who says Stackoverflow is a word? Is it in the dictionary? :)

Why is xstackoverflow or stt not a word? Who's dictionary are you using?

Are you just wanting to detect *unpronouncable* phonemes?

If you are wanting to compare a dictionary you will probably do to read up on [prefix trees (tries) as a method of storing dictionaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation).

I would also advise against using regex to match partial patterns, I've had difficulty getting relatively simple ones to match, never mind entire dictionaries.